# Change Format, Enter Cell, Press Enter, Vlookup Recognized

Tags: excel, vlookup

D1: Numbers "123456789", General Format --OR-- Letters "XYZ", General Format
E1: =IFERROR(IFERROR((VLOOKUP(D1,Lookup Array,2,FALSE))

1) The vlookup recognizes the Letters, and gives the correct output.
2) I know that the Number exists in the array- I can see it, but the vlookup comes up blank...

Here's the weird part, and I'm wondering if this has happened to anyone else:

2) If I change the format of D1 from General to Text,
3) Enter into the cell (as if I was going to type, but dont) 
4) then press enter...

**The vlookup suddenly displays the output!!**

Thoughts? Need more info? Let me know. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Seems like you're dealing with *text-that-looks-like-numbers*.

Comment: Shouldnt the vlookup recognize any format thought? IE why does it see the letter strings (set as general format) but not the numbers (also set as general format)?

Comment: Is this imported data? Is the number left-aligned? *Text-that-looks-like-numbers* is not numbers. Side note - "Number String" sounds like another way to say *text-that-looks-like-numbers*.

Comment: Ah! Okay: (1) the number is left aligned (2) at first it shows "General" format, but after changing it to "Text" format and entering into, then out of the cell, the vlookup works (3) the cell does show the little green corner "Number Stored As Text" with the option to convert to a number (4) but when I changed the format to "Number" 
 the vlookup no longer works.

Comment: Sorry deleted my comment... I reread yours. Keep it as text then, or change the data in *Lookup Array* to be actual numbers. You want to be consistent between `D1` and the lookup array.

Comment: Thank you. Okay, so maybe this is where Excel is freaking out- my vlookup is on Sheet A. The lookup array is on Sheet B. ~~But~~ the lookup array pulls its values from a pivot table... any ideas on how I would format the pivot table to make it work? It contains both numbers and letters (formatted as general.)

Comment: What is the source data for the pivot like?

Comment: BigBen- Thanks for your help! I tried changing the source, pivot, and reading values to number format, but it was no luck. The answer below on changing the VLOOKUP to include (TEXT(D1,"0")) worked. I feel like changing the format should have got it too- so I'm going to continue playing with that and see if I cant get it to work as well.

Comment: Changing to "Number" format doesn't actually convert *text-that-looks-like-numbers* to actual numbers. In a new cell, enter the number 1. Then copy that new cell, and select your original *text-that-looks-like-numbers*. Then Paste Special using the *Multiply* option. This is one way to convert them to actual numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change D1 to be TEXT(D1,”0”) in the VLOOKUP and this should force it to to look for the text value?

If the data was the other way round (if D1 was text and your lookup array was numbers) you could replace D1 with —D1 (two hyphens) to solve the issue